# What was meditation's part in psychology before third wave therapies?

Tags: meditation, history-of-psychology, mindfulness

I'm studying the history of meditation and/or mindfulness in psychology and am falling to find authors and resources speaking about it before its recent raise in popularity in western culture. Was meditation used in some forms of therapy before or should I expand my search into less scientific approaches to well-being like spirituality?

Comment: How far back would you wish to start? The ancient Greek Philosophers, learning from eastern sages called it omphaloskepsis leading to Philo of Alexandria and Plotinus developing "concentration techniques" - basically it developed alongside other forms of medicine. Could you clarify the objectives?

Comment: As far back as the Greek Philosophers! The objective is to show the evolution of meditation techniques and its involvement in psychology throughout the ages

Comment: An answer to that could comprise a series of books. Care to narrow the scope to something that might fit on a page here?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I'm not sure how to, my issue is that I don't know if meditation was even used, much less what to search or ask in order to get specific info about it

Comment: Well, you could start with [Freud](https://www.psychiatrictimes.com/view/psychotherapy-meditation-treatment-mental-suffering). As far as many are concerned, psychotherapy doesn't go back further than that.